# When one disables the root account via the terminal, what output can one expect?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root

When I used Ubuntu for the first time, my friends told me to enable the root account, and I enabled it.

But, I know that I already reinstalled Ubuntu few times, but in this last time, I don't know if I enabled the root account, so I tried to disabled it.

And few days ago, I saw that is not a very good idea to keep a root account enable, so I disabled it with: `sudo passwd -dl root`

But, what if I try to disable the root account, when It's not active? And what will the terminal say when I disable the account (here, the terminal said `passwd: password expiry information changed`).

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: Yes, that is the expected message when you use any of the options (`u`, `e`, `l`, `d`, etc.) that alter something (even if that something is already at the desired state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say that, if you try to disable the `root` account when it's not enabled, Ubuntu will just tell you so and exit. I think that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the question, the other one is what terminal writes when I disable the account (to confirm that I really disabled it).

Comment: @Nori-chan Run the command and see.

Comment: Just used the same command again, adn I got the same message (I included the message into the main post).

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, like muru said. @Nori-chan

Comment: So, I really disabled it? Now the root account is unusable?

Comment: @Nori-chan It should be. Test it by running `su`.

Comment: Tried running su, tried the password that my account always use and the password (that I think) that I used to enable the root user. Wrong password.

Comment: @Nori-chan Good. That means it's been disabled.

Comment: @Nori-chan do check if you had added an SSH key to root's authorized keys. A locked account can still be accessed using SSH via keys, and once they become root, passwords are no bar.

Comment: @muru I don't remember doing anything related to SSH. So I don't think that I added any SSH key (unless it's added by default).

Answer (score 2):

When you try to disable the root account but it is already disabled, `passwd` does *not* inform you that the root account was already disabled. But this is not a problem.

`passwd: password expiry information changed.` is the expected output of a successful run of `passwd -dl root`, even if the root password is already disabled. As [muru says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611858/when-one-disables-the-root-account-via-the-terminal-what-output-can-one-expect#comment860601_611858), `passwd` commands that change something will produce this output if they were able to write to the password database (which is usually `/etc/shadow`).

`passwd` was able to write the entry successfully. That it wrote the same thing that was already there doesn't mean it wasn't successful.

When `passwd` does fail, then you'll get another message reporting the error. For example, suppose you'd failed to run the command with `sudo`:

```
$ passwd -dl root
passwd: Permission denied.
```